# Does Ubuntu (Touch) support Unicode 9?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, unicode, emoji

Does Ubuntu (Touch) support Unicode 9 (with all the fancy new "emojis" discussed [here](http://www.cybershack.com.au/news/were-finally-getting-a-bacon-emoji-and-71-other-less-exciting-emojis-030616-2)) and if not, what version of Unicode *does* it support?

As you can see below, OTA-12 for Ubuntu (Touch) has a *lot* of colorful "emojis":
[image]

But I'm having trouble working out what version of Unicode is supported.

These "emojis" seem to work when sent to other people (using Android), but when I copy-and-paste codes for Unicode 9-specific "emojis", everyone sees the square-box thing... Suggesting that Unicode 9 is not yet supported by Ubuntu (Touch) OTA-12 or Android "M".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct, but [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/emoji-one-font-linux-unicode-9-0) (and [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/see-install-use-emoji-symbols-ubuntu-linux)) article on OMGUbuntu read to me like you just need a certain font that supports the characters you want to be displayed. Of course for something like an onscreen keyboard app the corresponding font would need to be integrated into the app.

As far as I can tell [ubuntu-keyboard](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/ubuntu-keyboard) is the corresponding source package and when I click round the dependencies a few times I land on [ubuntu-keyboard-data](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/trusty/ubuntu-keyboard-data) which links to the Droid font or to Droid fallback and the Noto font in newer releases.

Comparing the items in your screenshot with the ones for Noto on [emojipedia](http://emojipedia.org/google/) however indicate that the [emoji-one](http://emojipedia.org/emoji-one/) font is used instead. The corresponding package is probably fonts-emojione from the [stable phone overlay PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ci-train-ppa-service/+archive/ubuntu/stable-phone-overlay/+packages) which was last updated around 2016-06-17, so ideally Unicode 9 emojis should be integrated and work if you're up to date. I'm actually not sure how the parts come together.

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font) is an interesting link I just found, including a test page for emoji and some more information. No, I'm not saying one should install this on Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: FWIW I created the font mentioned in your edit for Linux in general, it should work in Ubuntu Touch though.